# What is the difference in versions of Joomla CMS i.e. Joomla 1.7 and joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7, joomla2.5

Please explain the difference.I know one difference is user management but what is also.

What is the difference in versions of **Joomla CMS** i.e. **Joomla 1.7** and **joomla 2.5** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest diffrence between joomla 1.5 and joomla 1.6 is user management .

In joomla 1.5 version are already default 5-6 user management.

But in joomla 1.6 version you create own user managment.

Comment: How is this the answer to the question? The question is about the difference between 1.7 and 2.5, of which there is almost no difference other than greater stability. For the end user, there isn't a choice here... 1.7 is deprecated (no longer supported) and 2.5 will be supported for a long time to come.

You mention Joomla 1.6. This is deprecated and has been for ages. If you are using it, upgrade IMMEDIATELY to 2.5 or get hacked.

How can you ask a question, answer it yourself with a both irrelevant and incorrect answer, and then accept your answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

One important consideration and difference is that version 1.7 reached end-of-life status on February 24, with version 1.7.5 being final release of that line.  What that means is there will be no further enhancements or bug fixes performed by the core Joomla team on version 1.7 going forward.

The official guidance from the Joomla development team is that 1.7.5 should only be used by those "who for some reason are unable to update to version 2.5.1."  The release blurb for 1.7.5 (found [here](http://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5411-joomla-175-released.html)) contains the guidance and EOL date mention.

As far as pure feature differences are concerned, the [page](http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/Issue-Jan-2012/item/654-What-s-new-in-Joomla-2-5) dedicated to detailing the new features in Joomla 2.5 does a better job than I could discussing them.  You may also want to take a look at the release notes for version 2.5.3 [here](http://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5416-joomla-253-released.html), as this is the latest release at the time of this answer.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The bigger the number, the more recent the release.

If developing a new website, you should use the most recent release of Joomla, which is Joomla 2.5.

Joomla 2.5 is just as painful to use, but more stable than, Joomla 1.7

Comment: I thought I should add - Joomla 2.5 is now at 2.5.1 - also, I've never found Joomla to be 'painful' to use.  There are so many awesome features in the newer releases (the ACL is great!!).  Not sure why the negativity for it overall, but the rest of the comment is correct.  1.7 was the short term support release which followed 1.6 (which introduced the new ACL as well as a host of other options 'under the hood').  2.5 is the Long Term Support release (which will be supported for the next couple years IIRC).

Comment: I have used Joomla for years. I design for it, I develop for it, I have expended countless hours providing support for it on the Joomla forums, etc. Joomla is my bread and butter.  
I like the existence of the new features in Joomla. But they are terribly implemented, and painful to use. More features != better usability. Joomla 2.5 is a step backwards from Joomla 1.5 in terms of usability. The new features are nice, but there are extensions that provide the same for J1.5. As far as i'm concerned, 2.5 was a failure.

Comment: I echo your enjoyment of Joomla Mark, although I respectfully disagree that 2.5 was a failure.  I still feel it was a huge step in a better direction.  In terms of usability the users who I have helped switch to 2.5 are able to do things now they just simply didn't understand before.  I think usability is there for them, and from a development standpoint - I certainly don't mind some of the features (particularly the ACL, which has made my life easier on a number of projects).  I'll agree to disagree about 2.5's failure, but I will agree to Joomla being awesome :-D

Comment: @Hanny I also love Joomla. Not sure about 2.5 either way. Hoping for a positive though. Would love to see your support of Joomla on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers

Comment: @Only Pritesh 2.5 is the next LTS, so if you are looking for something that will be supported for a while I would go with that.

Comment: I'm on there!  :-D  I too would love to see Joomla get it's own world of Q&A :)